# Oldest Operating System still in use today?

Tags: operating-systems, c

Reading through https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_operating_systems to decide where to port some library software—network|crypto|archive abstracting—I'm writing in C (C89).

DOS is definitely still in use today; and that takes us back to the 1980s.

Perhaps [V6 UNIX (1975)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_6_Unix)? - One of the early [BSDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution)?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic. See [Where to ask questions about computer science history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97786/where-to-ask-questions-about-computer-science-history)

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please make sure to put your question in the body of the post, and please use full sentences and proper grammar when stating the question.  The title is intended to be a summary of the post.  We're not like Quora; the title should not be just the first sentence of your post.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the question is answerable or whether it will be useful to others.  How would anyone know if there is one person somewhere in the world who is running some ancient OS without telling anyone?  How could anyone answer this question with confidence?  Why would anyone care?  What problem are you solving?  How would it be useful to future site visitors to have this question on the site?  Perhaps the question could be refined to put it into a form that will be answerable and useful to others.

Comment: I am creating families of new package managers and want to backport them as far as I can, in order to make believable a claim of futureproofing. Was porting to DOS when I thought : can I port a decade before DOS; to make the futureproof claim [even] more believable? - For example, the networking feature I build atop the OS provided library or libcurl; and libcurl itself has been rather widely ported - https://curl.se/download.html. - Including the old: AIX (1986+); DOS (1980s); HPE NonStop (1976 until ¿now?); and QNX (1982 until now).

Comment: IBM Mainframe and Midrange systems have far-reaching backwards compatibility. A z10 can still run /360 programs in VMs with the various /360 operating systems, which would get you back to 1964. There's a company in Japan still running a computer from 1959, although one could argue whether that is using an OS.

Comment: The question has to be edited to include the addendum. Also, this might better fit Retrocomputing SE, as this is not computer *science*.